# How do I parse a simple time string into a time period?

Tags: ruby, datetime

In my Ruby app, I have an `Investment` entity that has a `term` attribute.

I need this class to accept a String from user input in the form of `3 Years` or `36 months`. What I want is to then convert the input into number of months, set the `term` attribute to this period and figure out the maturity date.

So far I have tried using Active Support and Chronic but the APIs do not support this.

This getter works:

```
  def term
    if term =~ /year[s]?/i
      term = term.to_i * 12
    else term =~ /month[s]?/i
      term = term.to_i
    end
  end
```

But is there a more elegant way to do this in Ruby?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to parse the label you're showing to the user rather than passing an easier to compute value to your method. e.g. in a select box the option tags can show the label "3 years" but the option value would be the integer 36. So the user selects an easy to read text label but you pass an integer representing the number of months to your method, eliminating any need to parse the string.

Comment: Good question! But if that's the only need, I am good with your method.

Comment: @diego.greyrobot: Unless you want the user to have the flexibility of writing anything they want. (Although I agree that perhaps the `Investment` class isn't where this conversion should be happening)

Comment: @diego.greyrobot - good point but then would I check everytime whether the user means 36 months or 36 years?

Comment: @voithos where would you put it?

Comment: Treat the integers always as months, so if they pick "3 years" the option value would be 36.

Comment: I would think you'd want to normalize this information to be in a unit of something known, so just store the value in months always.

Comment: Don't allow free text, otherwise users will type stuff attempting to break your app. Instead, provide an interface that allows ONLY the format you want, such as a list for the numeric values, and one for the intervals.

Comment: @NickVeys storing months by default is not a bad idea but what if I want to be more flexible because I have observed investors using a very loose language around time periods. Sometimes they say years, sometimes they say months

Comment: Then seconds is probably your best bet.  ChronicDuration can parse things like `3 years` and `36 months` into seconds.  You do run into the problem that 3 years and 36 months aren’t the same depending on how you calculate it though!

Comment: @theTinMan: That's why you don't _let_ them break your app. You add error handling. You need this whether or not you allow free text.

Comment: @voithos, of course you use error-handling, that's common-sense and good programming. But allowing free text is a known path to frustrating users who don't know the syntax/language being allowed, whereas a good UI will rule those things out by removing opportunities for the user to do things wrong. At that point the error handling becomes easier because you know what should be coming at the code. Anything outside that narrow format gets rejected.

Comment: @theTinMan: Yes, obviously you don't want to define a DSL for every input form in your app. In that manner, free text is generally _not_ the right thing to use. But in some cases, it's difficult to have a good UI that is restrictive enough to avoid ambiguities, yet permissive enough to not annoy users (for example, adding ingredients to a recipe app). In such cases, _one option_ is to allow free text, along with some (hopefully) robust parsing, to give the user the flexibility that is needed. This may not be the case for OP, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby doesn't have anything built-in that represents a "time-span" (some other languages do). However, there is a [library for it (`timespan`)](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/timespan), although it may be a bit overkill for your situation.

You mentioned that `chronic` doesn't support this. But why not just calculate the time difference yourself?

```
require 'chronic'

input = '2 years'
then = Chronic.parse(input + ' ago')
now = Time.now

# Now we just calculate the number of months
term = (now.year * 12 + now.month) - (then.year * 12 + then.month)
```

That way, you get the flexibility of `chronic`'s parsing, and you still don't need much code.

Or just go ahead and use the `timespan` library.

```
require 'timespan'

term = Timespan.new('2 years').to_months
# Boom.
```

Answer (score 1):

If we can assume that the input string will always contain one or more digits followed a unit ("years", "Year", "months", etc.), this is pretty straightforward. Just write a regular expression that captures the digits and the unit, convert the digits to a number and normalize the unit, and do the math.

```
def to_months(str)
  if str =~ /(\d+)\s*(month|year)s?/i
    num = $1.to_i      # => 3
    unit = $2.downcase # => year

    num *= 12 if unit == "year"
    return num
  end

  raise ArgumentError, "Invalid input"
end

puts to_months("3 Years") # => 36
puts to_months("1 month") # => 1
puts to_months("6months") # => 6
```

It's not a whole lot more elegant than your method, but perhaps it'll give you an idea or two.